# How to dynamically add TableColumn to TableView in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Can someone suggest how to dynamicly add TableColumn to TableView in JavaFX?

I need to display class Row at tableView, but I know count of Nodes after another action. I've got trouble when I tried to use StringProperty from Node to set CellValueFactory. From Node class I need to display only reserved and reliability.

```
public class Row {
private int step;
private Node[] nodes;
private double p = 1;
private double c;
private StringProperty stepProperty;
private StringProperty pProperty;
private StringProperty cProperty;

Row(int step, Node[] nodes, double c){
    this.step = step;
    this.nodes = nodes;
    for (Node node:
         nodes) {
        p *= node.getReliability();
    }
    this.c = c;
}

public int getStep() {return step;}

public Node getNode(int index) {return nodes[index];}

public double getP() {return p;}

public double getC() {return c;}

public StringProperty stepProperty() {
    this.stepProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(step + "");
    return stepProperty;
}

public StringProperty pProperty() {
    this.pProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(p + "");
    return pProperty;
}

public StringProperty cProperty() {
    this.cProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(c + "");
    return cProperty;
} }

public class Node {
private StringProperty reserved;
private StringProperty reliability;
private StringProperty price;

Node(String reserved, String reliability, String price){
    this.reserved = new SimpleStringProperty(reserved);
    this.reliability = new SimpleStringProperty(reliability);
    this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
}

public StringProperty reliabilityProperty() {
    return reliability;
}

public StringProperty priceProperty() {
    return price;
}

public StringProperty reservedProperty() {
    return reserved;
}

public double getReliability(){
return Double.parseDouble(reliability.get());}

public int getPrice(){return Integer.parseInt(price.get());}

public int getReserved(){return Integer.parseInt(reserved.get());}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want the table to look like? It's not really clear.

Comment: Look, for example if i have 2 nodes i need to display at tableView
Row.Step | Node[0].reserved | Node[0].reliability | Node[1].reserved | Node[2].reliability | Row.p | Row.c

Comment: OK, that helps. Does every `Row` object have the same number of nodes in the array it contains?  What happens if different `Row` objects have different numbers of nodes? Do you add new `Row` objects while the table is displayed? When do you "know" how many nodes the `Row` objects have?

Comment: Yes, every Row object has the same number of nodes. 
I know count of Nodes before that moment when I need to display it.

Comment: Maybe not relevant, but why on earth do the property methods in the `Row` class create a new property object every time you call them?

Comment: Why don't you [edit] the question to include the additional information that was needed to provide an answer. Maybe that way it will stop attracting downvotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need something along the following lines:

```
TableView<Row> table = new TableView<>();

int numNodes = ... ;

TableColumn<Row, Number> stepCol = new TableColumn<>("Step");
stepCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().stepProperty());
table.getColumn().add(stepCol);

for (int n = 0 ; n < numNodes ; n++) {
    final int nodeIndex = n ;
    TableColumn<Row, String> reservedCol = new TableColumn<>("Reserved - "+nodeIndex);
    reservedCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNode(nodeIndex).reservedProperty());

    TableColumn<Row, String> reliabilityCol = new TableColumn<>("Reliability - "+nodeIndex);
    reliabilityCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNode(nodeIndex).reliabilityProperty());

    table.getColumns().add(reservedCol);
    table.getColumns().add(reliabilityCol);
}

TableColumn<Row, String> pCol = new TableColumn<>("P");
stepCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().pProperty());
table.getColumn().add(pCol);

TableColumn<Row, String> cCol = new TableColumn<>("C");
stepCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().cProperty());
table.getColumn().add(cCol);
```